# Using a procedure to update Column 2 in a Table A, by checking if column 1 value is present in a column in Table B [PostgreSQL]

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have two tables as follows:

**Table A: Name, ID, value**

**Table B: ID, title**

`TableA.value` is dependent on whether `TableA.ID` is present in `TableB.ID`.

I am trying to create a procedure and trigger so that whenever `TableB` is modified, the procedure is triggered to check if `TableA.ID` is in `TableB.ID` and sets `TableA.value` to 10.

I am using the following code and getting an error:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE update1
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
UPDATE tablA as a
SET a.value = 10
WHERE a.ID EXISTS ( SELECT b.ID 
                            FROM tableB as b
                           WHERE a.ID = b.ID)
$$;
```

I am an SQL noob, and this is the first time I am trying to use a procedure.

**UPDATE**

I was able to create a procedure which does the job when I manually run it using `CALL`

However, it does not have a `RETURNS TRIGGER` block within it. Adding that returns the error *Procedure cannot return triggers*.

If I create a trigger as follows

```
CREATE TRIGGER b_trigger
AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT ON b.ID
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update1();
```

However, this returns the following

*ERROR:  function columbia_deli.manager_discount must return type trigger*

*SQL state: 42P17*

Comment: You don't need to create procedure to update the row in other table. Using Trigger only would work fine. Just create  a AFTER_UPDATE trigger. https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/postgresql-triggers.php

Comment: @Abhishek In PostgreSql you have to write a function for trigger. Read the blog

Comment: @AkhileshMishra : Yes, You are right but OP is actually creating a procedure not function.

Comment: Correct.. In Postgresql Procedure is introduced with version 11. Earlier only functions were there

Comment: @AkhileshMishra Yes, I referred him to  the blog.so, that he can get the deep understanding of Triggers in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Well, if you want to write a trigger you need to use a function which is [clearly documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html)

Comment: You must try must my code as it is.

Comment: Yeah. I was able to create the function. I got confused because the documentation mentions procedure but in a later section mentions triggers can only use function and the word procedure in the sample code is redundant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using `plpgsql` Language:

**Trigger Function:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update1()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
 
begin
update "TableA" set value= 10 where id =new.id;

return NEW;
end;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Then create trigger on  `TableB` for `after update` event

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_tableb
  AFTER UPDATE
  ON "TableB"
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE update1();
```

Comment: Thanks. When I try something similar, an error shows up saying Functions cannot return triggers.

Comment: @KarthicSubramanian: then it seems you are not using Postgres. What does `select version();` show you?

Comment: PostgreSQL 12.3 (Debian 12.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit

Comment: @KarthicSubramanian: you need to use a function, not a procedure for a trigger

Comment: @KarthicSubramanian i think you are using language SQL. Please use language `plpgsql`. This error will come with `SQL` language.